# Output not printing to txt file Java

Tags: java, permutation, printwriter

I am trying to create a program which prints out all the possible combinations of the letters "AUGC".
The output would really print to a txt file and the result would be a txt file with something like this:
"AAA
AAG
AAC
AAU
AGA"
etc
Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Permute {

    static String s = "ACGU";

    static void permute(int level, String prefix) {

        if (level == 0) {
            String fileName = "out.txt";
            PrintWriter outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);
                outputStream.println(prefix);
                System.out.println(prefix);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            permute(level - 1, prefix + s.charAt(i));
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 2;
        permute(k, "");
    }   

}
```

Currently the program is printing all the output to the console and only the last permutation to the txt file.
I would like it to print all the information to both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are overwriting the file each time when permute is called. Have a look at the javadoc for [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

Comment: Keep the PrintWriter open till you finish writing all permutations.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing OutputStream prematurely. Since you are using recursion, pass OutputStream as a parameter to permute method from main method.  Initialize stream and close it in main method.

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong on this one but do you not need to include a "\n" as part of your outputStream.println(prefix);

so that is looks like 
outputStream.println(prefix + "\n");

This will help as it seems to replacing the line with the newest details and not on a new line which is what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Why? lol,  its looks like every time they run the try catch block it is replacing the old data with the new as files don't automatically use the next line without being told to. explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: So you didn't [look it up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)): "Prints a String and then terminates the line." So adding another `"\r"` just adds a line terminator, i.e. a blank line. And it doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: `I maybe wrong on this `. If you may be wrong on this then why are you answering lol.